# aws-cli - Filter output with --query or --filter

Tags: aws-cli

I try to list all my AutoScalingGroups  with "Desiredcapacity" = 3.
I can run this but it gives me all ASG back and it's to many.

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query "AutoScalingGroups[*].{NAME:AutoScalingGroupName,DesiredCapacity:DesiredCapacity} | sort_by([], &DesiredCapacity)" --profile MyProfile --output table
```

I tried :

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query "AutoScalingGroups[?DesiredCapacity == '3'].{NAME:AutoScalingGroupName,DesiredCapacity:DesiredCapacity} | sort_by([], &DesiredCapacity)" --profile MyProfile --output table
```

I dont get any error msg but it does not return anything, as it should

Answer (score 0):

I actually improved my search and find a solution.

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query 'AutoScalingGroups[?DesiredCapacity>=`3`].[AutoScalingGroupName,DesiredCapacity,MinSize,MaxSize]' --output table --profile MyProfile
```

is exactly what i want.